# Variance matrix from polar to cartesian coordinates

Tags: r, math, sta

I am dealing with a time series in polar coordinates and I am applying the Kalman filter for predictions. The time series is related with the satellite orbite.

However my prediction and estimation for the variance are expressed in polar coordinates [r,theta].

I know how to convert my prediction in cartesian coordinates with the function

```
  f(r,theta) <- [r*cos(theta),r*sin(theta)].
```

But I do not know how to deal with the variance since it is not a linear operator.

I provide you my data in order if you can help me with the transformation:

```
     Radius                  Angle        
[1,] "39805.9613778309" "1.46134492279737"
[2,] "39805.9613778309" "1.48689546833425"
[3,] "39805.9613778309" "1.51244601387112"
[4,] "39805.9613778309" "1.537996559408"  
[5,] "39805.9613778309" "1.56354710494488"
[6,] "39805.9613778309" "1.58909765048176"
```

And the variance matrix for the first prediction is :

```
        radius    theta
[1,] 5132782 0.000000000
[2,]       0 0.001646994
```

I would like to know how to obtain this matrix in cartesian coordinates for the first prediction. thanks!

Comment: This feels more of a theoretical question, and therefor more ontopic for CrossValidated SE.

Comment: I believe that there is no way to obtain the variance of the cartesian coordinates from the polar one. At least not accurately. Can you recreate the variance matrix from the cartesian data? Is an approximate answer, obtained from a local linearization, acceptable? And one more thing: what does the [tag:sta] tag denote, and are you sure that this is appropriate here? This questions doesn't seem to fit others from that tag.

Comment: Maybe you can find what you are looking for here: http://www.centerforspace.com/downloads/files/pubs/AAS-03-526.pdf  It is a paper by David Vallado about coordinate transformations of the covariance matrix. It includes a section from satellite spherical coordinates (lat, long, alt) to cartesian, Earth-centered coordinates. Not exactly what you need, but you can simplify it to your needs.

Answer (score 3):

This had me perplexed as well. I think I found the answer: the formula provided above,

[image: errorprop],

follows from the most general form of error propagation. The formula is correct, provided you're OK with making a few assumptions, in particular that you are OK with linearizing the transformation.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty#Non-linear_combinations. This section has a subsection, 'Caveats and Warnings,' which I think is worth approaching with an open mind (so you don't end up biased :P ).

Answer (score 2):

In developing tracking filters for radar systems, I've used the following technique:

1) Determine the polar to Cartesian rotation matrix as

```
  R = [cos(theta)  - sin(theta);
       sin(theta)    cos(theta)]
```

2) Perform the following matrix multiplication to obtain the covariance matrix in Cartesian coordinates, Pcart:

```
  Pcart = R*Ppol*R'

  where Ppol is the covariance matrix in polar coordinates
        R' is the transpose of R
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to accomplish this is to find the Jacobian of the function Fhat = Jacobian[f(r,theta)]. If the variance matrix in spherical is R(polar), then P(Cart) = Fhat*R*Fhat'. Using a Rotation matrix gives you the wrong answer, as it simply rotates the Cartesian covariance into another 'rotated' Cartesian system. See the Appendix 18.B in my book "Bayesian Estimation and Tracking: A Practical Guide" for a complete derivation of this formula and how to use it.